# Проверка типов в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Есть проблема с проверкой типов в TypeScript. Есть интерфейс следующего вида:

```
export interface ObjectRow {
    _id?: string;
    id: string;
    value: string | number;
    modificatedDate: number;
}
```

В какой-то момент происходит получение объекта типа ObjectRow, и требуется совершить некие действия, если в value пришла непустая строка. Написано такое условие для проверки:

```
if (typeof object.value === 'string' && object.value.length > 0) {...}
```

Однако в этом месте вылетает ошибка: **"Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'"**.

По идее, не проходит первая часть условия, то вторая должна игнорироваться - но этого почему-то не происходит: TypeScript считает, что раз есть возможность прихода числа, то проверка на length некорректна. Я уже на несколько раз переписал условие - TypeScript все равно его зарубает. Можете ли подсказать, где копать? В TypeScript я пока что новичок, продолжаю усиленно гуглить. Буду благодарен за любые рекомендации.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрим оф документацию по Union types.
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

для вашего случая правим так:

```
const value = object.value;
if (typeof value === 'string' && (<string>value).length > 0) { ...}
```

или

```
if (typeof object.value === 'string' && (object.value as string).length > 0) { ... }
```

второе придумали для TSX.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: @overthesanity оператор `as` это приведение типа. А у нас же union.

Comment: @kostyawh  достаточно принять ответ.

Comment: @Hooter, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SomeObject%20%7B%0A%20%20value%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20object%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20value%3A%2010%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20object.value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string'%20%26%26%20object.%3Cstring%3Evalue.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%7D

Comment: @overthesanity, да Вы правы, надо так:

Answer (score 1):

Обнови тайпскрипт - [всё работает](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20ObjectRow%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_id%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20modificatedDate%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x%3A%20ObjectRow%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string'%20%26%26%20x.value.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x.value)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

[image: скриншот]

А вообще, гораздо лучше было проверить так:

```
if (typeof x.value === 'string' && x.value)
```